# Xcode commit view: keyboard shortcut for jumping to the next change?

Tags: keyboard, xcode

When I commit my code from Xcode (File -> Source Control -> Commit), is there a command (that can be assigned a shortcut presumably) to jump to the next change in the commit view? This will allow to quickly go over the changes spanned across multiple files being committed. Otherwise there is some mouse work to do, which is not very productive.

Answer (score 8):

I'm unsure of the version that this feature became available, but you can jump to the next and last change of the currently viewed file (Navigate -> Jump to Next/Previous Change). The shortcut is `^ \` for next and `^ |` for previous.

This can be used on Standard and Assistant editor, but NOT Source Control Editor.

I can confirm that this feature is available in Xcode 10.1 and Xcode 10.2

Comment: So excited to find this, thanks for posting